# pandas: DTypeWarning, but I specified dtypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a Pandas Dataframe using the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('../table.csv.gz', nrows=10000,
                 index_col=False, engine='c',
                 true_values=[b'1'], false_values=[b'0'],
                 usecols=usecols, dtype=dtype)
```

And I get the following warning:

`DtypeWarning: Columns (5,2397,2402,2449) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.`

But the columns have their header name present in `dtype`. The specified type of all these columns is `np.bool`, and the only values present in those columns in the csv file are `'1'` and `''` (nothing between the commas. This gives a column that has type `object`, and becomes type `bool` when calling `DataFrame.fillna`).

Furthermore, when I edit the CSV file to remove all columns except the offending ones to try and pinpoint the source of the warning, the warning stops happening.

What is going on? Is this a bug in `read_csv`? Should I just ignore the warning?

Comment: Since the file is so large, it is likely reading it and processing it in chunks. It tries to store the column as `np.bool`, but the missing values force it to store that chunk as `object`. Pandas uses `np.nan` to represent missing values, so the column must be either `object` or `float` until the missing values are replaced. The warning is telling you that you might have mixed `dtypes` in your dataframe as a result of reading it in chunks. Have you tried specifying `object` or `float` for the `dtype` of those columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess your problem is when you're reading the file you actually have two different types of values for those columns: np.bool('1') and np.nan(''), so actually if you are telling it to consider the column as np.bool it won't do it. I think you can try using the same just changing the false_values parameter to false_values = [b'']

```
df = pd.read_csv('../table.csv.gz', nrows=10000,
             index_col=False, engine='c',
             true_values=[b'1'], false_values=[b''],
             usecols=usecols, dtype=dtype)
```

If that doesn't work you could also do:

```
df.loc[:,[5,2397,2402,2449]].fillna('0',inplace = True)
df.to_csv('../table.csv.gz')
```

Now when you read it back you actually have 0s where  you should.

```
df = pd.read_csv('../table.csv.gz', nrows=10000,
             index_col=False, engine='c',
             true_values=[b'1'], false_values=[b'0'],
             usecols=usecols, dtype=dtype)
```

Comment: Hm, re-editing the file so that it works well could be good. Thanks I'll do that. However, it's very odd that precisely these columns are raised as a warning. I have at least 20 more boolean columns that have empty values.